# Bayesian Linear Regression - Creating a distribution for a new prediction

Tags: regression, bayesian, predictive-models, posterior

I'm using MCMC to fit a linear regression model with the end goal of making predictions for new observations. See reproducible example below:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(MCMCpack)
library(dplyr)
data(mpg)
attach(mpg)

# Variance of hwy for each trans category
# Some categories e.g. auto(s5) have a bigger variance
# How can I make the distribution for a new prediction reflect this?
vars <- mpg %>% 
  group_by(trans) %>% 
  summarise(hwy_var=var(hwy)) %>% 
  ungroup()

# Fit model
bm <- MCMCregress(hwy ~ year + cyl + trans + cty)

# Want to find distribution of hwy for new data point
new_obs <- data.frame(year=1999, cyl=4, trans="auto(l6)", cty=16)
```

What I want to capture in predicting `hwy` for the `new_obs` is a predictive distribution, taking into account its predictor values. For example, `auto(l6)` is a category with a larger `hwy` variance (as seen in  `vars`) so I'd like the predictive distribution for this point to be wider. Is this possible with Bayesian statistics? Or any other method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for the [posterior predictive distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posterior_predictive_distribution). So, what you could do is the following. Suppose that $(\beta^{(s)},\sigma^{(s)})$ is the $s$th posterior sample of your parameter vector, consisting of the regression coefficients including the intercept and the residual standard deviation. Further, let $\mathbf x$ be the set of predictor values for which you want to have the prediction (e.g., (`1999`, `4`,...)), where the first element of $\mathbf x$ is a one. Using your $s=1,2,...,S$ posterior samples of $(\beta^{(s)},\sigma^{(s)})$, calculate $\hat y^{(s)} = \mathbf x^\top \beta^{(s)} $ and then draw $\tilde y^{(s)}$ from $\text{Normal}(\hat y^{(s)}, \sigma^{(s)})$. This will give you $S$ draws from the posterior predictive distribution at $\mathbf x$.

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for, just really needed someone to lay out the step-by-step. Thanks a lot